# Visa effect of difference in marital status on passport vs reality

Tags: passports, weddings

I got my passport when I was single. I then married and divorced after 7-8 months. Now I am applying for a visa where it asks for marital status as: singe/never married, divorced and so on. Do I need to choose the single/never married option or the divorced one? I am confused as my passport mentions SINGLE. Will it affect my visa decision?

Comment: You should write a note in your visa application on this, so they won't think it was a mistake or you lied.

Comment: Is it common for passports to list marital statuses?

Comment: The question is 'Are you single or divorced?'. You've just told us you're divorced. The answer seems pretty straight forward..

Comment: @Rob The question is, will it affect her chances of having her visa approved if the marital status on her passport is different than what it currently is. And if so, how should she act upon that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what country actually lists marital status on the passport? I just double-checked my US one and it doesn't.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Always, always, always tell the truth in your applications. If someone notices a discrepancy, you have the explanation: the passport was issued before the marriage and divorce.

As to whether this will affect the application, that depends on what kind of visa you are applying for, to which country, and many other details you have left out of your question. But there isn't a visa in the world where "lie on your application so it matches the out-of-date information from when your passport was issued" is the right thing to do.

Comment: What if someone was common-law married even though it wasn't made official? If another county is asking about marriage/divorce should the applicant use their home jurisdiction's definition of marriage or the destination country's definition? What about gay marriage in countries that don't recognise gay marriage - and do civil-partnerships count as well?

Comment: interesting questions, worth asking as questions of their own. But be sure to be specific about the country pairs involved. A general answer will not exist.

Comment: Kate, I think @Dai was trying to suggest that in some cases there might be a need or justification to 'lie' on an application if it will not fit into the world view of the country one is applying for.  So there might be some fringe case where it is the right thing to do and possibly even sanctioned.

Comment: @KalleMP but that has nothing to do with this question. If country A asks if you're married and doesn't consider you married, you might answer No. This is about the truth being out of sync with the stale data on the passport.

Comment: Kate, I agree, it is just that your answer was rather firm about the __Always, always, always__ and @Dai, like me, was probably thinking it might not be so for every __visa in the world__.

Comment: But it's still not lying. "Are you married by our definition of married?" "No" is not lying.

Comment: @KalleMP don't lie when it comes to this stuff. Please stop creating FUD.